# Do Lipschitz convex functions have at least one "small" subgradient at each point?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lipschitz-functions, subgradient

Let $X \subset \mathbb R^d$ be closed and convex and $f: X \to \mathbb R$ be convex and Lipschitz. That means there is $L > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \le L \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y \in X$. Here $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm. We define the subgradient sets:

$$\partial_f(x) = \{v \in \mathbb R^d: f(y) \ge f(x)+ v \cdot(y-x) \ \forall y \in X\}.$$

It seems common practice (For example Lemma 2.6 of [this survey](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/papers/OLsurvey.pdf) ) to claim  each subgradient of $f$ has norm at most $L$. Unfortunately this is not true $-$ the proof in the survey only works under the assumption that $x$ is an interior point of $X$.

If we allow boundary points here is a   counterexample: Let $X=[0,1]$ and $f(x) = x$ and $L=1$. Then at each interior point $\partial_f(x) = \{1\}$ which is clearly bounded by $L$. However at the boundary we have $\partial_f(0) = (-\infty,1]$ since for any $y \in [0,1]$ and $v \le 1$ we have $y \ge vy$ and so
$$f(y) = y \ge 0 + vy = 0+v(y-x) =f(x)+v(y-x).$$
Likewise $\partial_f(0) = [1,\infty)$.

However I notice there still exists a small subgradient at each endpoint, even if there are many more large ones. Namely $1$ is still a subgradient at the endpoints. I wonder is this fact true in general?

> **Conjecture:** Let $X \subset \mathbb R^d$ be closed and convex and $f: X \to \mathbb R$ be convex and Lipschitz with constant $L$. For each $x \in X$ there is $v \in \partial_f(x)$ with $\|v\| \le L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  We may assume that $X$ has nonempty interior (otherwise it's contained in an affine subspace, and we can extend the function by making it constant on the orthogonal complement...).  Now any $x \in X$ is the limit of a sequence $x_n$ in the interior of $X$, and at each $x_n$ there is a subgradient $v_n$ with norm  $\le L$.  The $v_n$ have a limit point, which is a subgradient at $x$ and has norm $\le L$.

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea about this follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4023060/do-lipschitz-convex-functions-have-at-least-one-small-normal-subgradient-at-ea

Comment: How do you know that the $v_n$ have a limit point?

Comment: @AisforAmbition Any bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^d$ has a limit point.